# C# IF statement gives incorrect result

Tags: c#

I seem to have stumbled on a circumstance where the C# IF statement gives an incorrect result. I was attempting to write a version of Equals() to deep compare two instances of a class.

Here is a simple test case with some debug:

```
namespace IfTest
{
class MyClass
{
    public string String1
    { get; set; }
    public int Int1
    { get; set; }
    public float Float1
    { get; set; }
    public bool Bool1
    { get; set; }

    public MyClass(string s, int i, float f, bool b)
    {
        String1 = s;
        Int1 = i;
        Float1 = f;
        Bool1 = b;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object otherInstance)
    {
        bool isEqual = true;
        MyClass other = (MyClass)otherInstance;
        int good = 0, bad = 0;

        // Compare everything in 'other' to 'this', using reflection
        Type sourceType = other.GetType();
        Type destinationType = this.GetType();

        foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProperty in sourceType.GetProperties())
        {
            PropertyInfo destinationProperty = destinationType.GetProperty(sourceProperty.Name);
            if (destinationProperty == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Destination {0} is null", sourceProperty.Name);
                isEqual = false;
                bad++;
            }
            else
            {
                var x = sourceProperty.GetValue(other);
                var y = destinationProperty.GetValue(this);
                //if (sourceProperty.GetValue(other, null) != destinationProperty.GetValue(this, null))

                if (x != y)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name {0}: {1} {2} different", sourceProperty.Name, x, y);
                    isEqual = false;
                    bad++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Name {0}: {1} {2} same", sourceProperty.Name, x, y);
                    good++;
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Good: {0}. Bad {1}", good, bad);
        return isEqual;
    }
}
}


using System;

namespace IfTest
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass a = new MyClass("abc", 23, 45.67F, false);
        MyClass b = new MyClass("abc", 23, 45.67F, false);

        // Test IF usually works with var's
        var i = a.Int1;
        var j = b.Int1;
        Console.WriteLine("Main test {0}",
            (i == j) ? "OK" : "Fail");

        a.Equals(b);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
}
```

In MyClass.Equals() I have commented out the line 
    `if (sourceProperty.GetValue(other, null) != destinationProperty.GetValue(this, null))`

and put the 2 property values in temporary variables.

Running this gives:

```
Main test OK
Name String1: abc abc same
Name Int1: 23 23 different
Name Float1: 45.67 45.67 different
Name Bool1: False False different
Good: 1. Bad 3
```

which shows that the IF fails for numeric types. The same result occurs if I change the x and y assignments to:
    `var x = sourceProperty.GetValue(other);`
    `var y = sourceProperty.GetValue(other);`

I can work round it by adding something like:

```
if (x is int)
{
    if ((int) x == (int)y)
        Console.WriteLine("INT Name {0}: {1} {2} same", sourceProperty.Name, x, y);
}
```

but I would have to test every numeric type.

Is this a C# problem or have I done something silly? I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Desktop version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4, .Net version 4.5.50938 and Visual C# 2013.

Comment: is there a reason you're using reflection to do this instead of direct property comparison?

Comment: You misunderstand what `var` means. It's not `dynamic`. It just causes the *compiler* to infer the type. There's no runtime difference between `var x = sourceProperty.GetValue(other);` and `object x = sourceProperty.GetValue(other);`

Comment: That does not equate. You know that `a == b` and `a != b` is not the same as `a.Equals(b)` and `!a.Equals(b)` right? And that `PropertyInfo.GetValue()` returns a `sytem.object` reference?

Comment: I thought `object` comparisons like that test the references, not the values even if it truly is an `int`.

Answer (score 5):

The comparisons fail because you're using the `==` operator on the `Object` type - which performs a reference-equality operation rather than a value-equality operation, furthermore the reflection API in the .NET Framework does not cache and re-return pregenerated reflection object instances, which is why this returns false:

```
foo.GetType().GetMethod("Bar") == foo.GetType().GetMethod("Bar")
```

Another problem is you're using the `var` keyword inappropriately: it's hiding the fact you're boxing value-types. The type of `x` and `y` is a boxed-`int` as `Object`, hence why it performs a reference equality comparison instead of value-equality.

The solution is to explicitly call the `.Equals` method on reference types, and unbox value types by casting to their real type:

```
foo.GetType().GetMethod("Bar").Equals( foo.GetType().GetMethod("Bar") )

Int32 x = (Int32)sourceProperty.GetValue(other);
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who pointed out the boxing issue. Using .Equals() fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `GetValue`, you're getting an `object` back.  When the value is an `int`, that `int` is boxed as an `object` then returned.  Now, when you use `==` to compare two *boxed ints*, the `==` operator from the `object` class is used.  When you cast to `int`, it is now using the `==` operator from `int`.  These do two different things, as you've found.

This returns false:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", (object)5 == (object)5);
```

This returns true:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", ((object)5).Equals((object)5));
```

You can use the `.Equals()` method to do your equality checking.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what you are comparing, the result makes sense.

If you specify the variable types instead of using the `var` keyword, you would know that the variables are objects:

```
object x = sourceProperty.GetValue(other);
object y = destinationProperty.GetValue(this);
```

Whatever the type of the property that you are using reflection to read, the return value of the `GetValue` method is `object`.

For reference types the variable values will be the reference. For value types the variable values will be the reference to an object that the value is boxed in.

For reference types the comparison works, as the variables point directly to the objects. For strings the method `String.Equals` will be found and used. For value types the object that boxes the value doesn't have an equality comparer for the value, so the `Object.Equals` method will be used, which compares the references to the objects, not the values in the objects.

This can be shown with a much simpler example:

```
object x = 1;
object y = 1;
Console.WriteLine(x == y);
```

Output:

```
False
```

Eventhough the objects contains the same boxed values, the comparison returns `false` as the references are different.

Answer (score 0):

You code is wrong because GetValue returns an object and thus two different object

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You have to first GetValue and then cast it if it is casetable and compare the two ( which will be value type)